# Linking unistd.h when using CC compiler (Solaris)

Tags: c, solaris, cc, unistd.h

I need to link `<unistd.h>` in my program using CC compiler on Solaris. When I needed to link `<math.h>` or `<curses.h>` I just used Google to find `-lm` and `-lcurses` flags but this time Google didn't help. How to find out in which `lib*something*` is `<unistd.h>` located?

Comment: `<unistd.h>` is a header that is included. It is not linked in. Neither is a `<math.h>` **in** the `libm`; it just *describes its contents*.

Comment: the functions exposed by `unistd.h` are all contained in the `libc.so` library, which is always linked in,  so nothing has to be done at link time (unlike the libcurses.so and libmath.so libraries.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any given function, the man page tells you both what headers to include and what libraries to link.

For example, [the `ceil` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5172/6mbb7btc5/index.html):

> Synopsis
>
> ```
> c99 [ flag... ] file... -lm [ library... ]
> #include <math.h>
>
> double ceil(double x);
>
> float ceilf(float x);
>
> long double ceill(long double x);
> ```

It tells you to `#include <math.h>` and to link with `-lm`.

Most functions declared in `<unistd.h>` don't require any additional libraries to link in, but when in doubt check the man pages.